# CentOS 5 Manual / User Guide

Tags: centos-5

I just got a laptop for work with CentOS 5 installed on it. I am looking for a good reference guide or user manual. I have basic Linux experience and like something to help me along as I get use to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has helped me out: http://www.centos.org

Answer (score 1):

99% of the [RHEL documentation](http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/enterprise/#RHEL5) applies to it.

Comment: That seems to be mostly for admins, I am not an admin but rather a user. I need something little more user/newbie friendly